# Oracle: Prevent a stored procedure from running outside of production environment

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

We have a scheduled task in our Oracle production environment that runs a stored procedure to copy data between identical schemas in dev and prod. (This is a stop-gap solution to a business problem until our dev staff has time to address it properly.)

We periodically refresh our dev and test environments by copying scrubbed data from prod. The copy includes tasks and stored procedures. If the stored procedure runs on any server except those in production, we risk corrupting data, so I have to remember to tell the DBAs to disable the task in dev and test.

**Is there a way (via pl/sql?) to prevent a stored procedure from running outside of our production environment?**

As a fail-safe, the procedure uses an alias that is not defined in dev or test, I would prefer to avoid the errors that generates.

Comment: Why isn't it as simple as checking the schema name to see if it is prod, and tossing an exception if not?

Comment: The answer may be that simple! I'm ok with SQL, but far from an expert.

Comment: You can query v$database and check the instance_name (or hostname) - I prseume Prod and Dev db SIDs will differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a mechanism for identifiying which database the procedure is running on, and preferably one which is available to a schema without additional grants.  The `global_name` view fits the bill.

Start the main call of your routine with an assertion like this:

```
 begin
     select global_name 
     into l_name
     from global_name;

     if l_name != 'PROD' then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Can only run this procedure in Production');
     end if;
     ....
```

This presumes that your Production database has a sensible unique name.  If not, there are other possible identifiers exposed through [the USERENV namespace for SYS_CONTEXT()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions184.htm#SQLRF51825), e.g. `instance_name`,  `service_name` or `host`.

In any case be careful if you operate a distributed production environment - RAC, DataGuard, etc.  Also, such an assertion will create problems for testing.  It could be [interesting](http://memegenerator.net/instance/9689481).

Comment: As a follow-up... I used INSTANCE_NAME (SELECT INSTANCE_NAME FROM v$instance;) since global_name in all of our dev, test and staging environments came back "PROD" LOL.